# How to create file as another user via C/C++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-permissions, chown

Linux C/C++ has `open` or `fopen` API, but created file are belong to process uid.

If we want to change owner/group of this file, we can use `chown` or `fchown` API after file created.

But, is there one API for creating file as another user, not two API ?

Comment: No, there isn't any API for this. Ordinary users aren't even allowed to do this.

Comment: You can only change the ownership of a file as `root`, and there are no means to create a file, even for `root` owned by some other uid or gid.

Comment: Change who the process is running as before the file is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Unix api dedicated for that, but you can change the current user to
other user before create the file, such as:

1. Make sure you have permission. The current effective user must be "root" OR set user or group ID on executable file.
2. Call `setgid` and `setuid` to other user.
3. Create the file.
4. Call `setuid` and `setgid` to old user if required.

Because the user is process-wide, if your program is multi-threaded, you may
need to fork a child process doing the steps I listed before.

But if you want non-root user (such as nobody) to run your program, you can give
the permission to your executable file:

```
sudo chown root:root ./your_app && sudo chmod gu+s ./you_app
```

Now you can call `setuid(0)` and `setgid(0)` to acquire root permission.

Comment: You don't need to call `setuid(0)` or `setgid(0)` because the effective uid will be `0` (because of the `s` bit) which allows you to directly set the uid to other user.

Comment: You need to call `setgid()` before you call `setuid()` — otherwise, the `setgid()` will fail because the process no longer has root privileges.  Traditionally, if a process with `root` privileges calls `setuid()` to set a non-zero (non-root) UID, you can't change the effective UID back to `root` (so the saved UID is reset).  This is necessary so that programs like `login` work as expected — without giving ordinary users a way to become `root` without going through programs such as `sudo` or `su`.

Comment: Also, you should mention the [`chown`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html) system call options because that is more general. They only require the `CAP_CHOWN`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in Linux.

Allowing this could cause some subtle security bugs (remote code execution, destroying files of other users, etc.) and therefore is not allowed.

Instead, please just run the process under `sudo`.

Comment: I would argue that fork and exec suid root binary (be it sudo or custom binary which performs extra checks on file to be created) is API which allows doing this. So first paragraph is kinda incorrect iMO. It *is* possible if you have admin access at install time.

Comment: @hyde: That's an alternative definition of API.  If you're working at the system call level (as the question seems to be), then executing other programs (even `sudo`) is not really the API — yes, it uses `fork()` and `exec*()`, but it isn't a simple system call which the term API is normally used to describe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Depends if you consider "Linux" as an operating system (so you can for example consider C standard library or the usual Linux libraries as available APIs), or as a kernel (in which case only syscalls, special files under /dev and /proc, etc can be counted as API). The question talks about OS libraries (mentions `fopen`).

Comment: Or, to put it another way, you can certainly wrap "create file as another user" as a package you can install in basically any Linux, which would provide a .so library, a .h file for building software using the library, and the helper "suid root" binary (either daemon available through some IPC mechanism or as a binary run with `fork` and `exec`) used by the library. So in that sense this is quite possible in Linux, the kernel provides APIs which allow doing this from application perspective as a simple library function call.